# Applying FOLD on Binary tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I have a small haskell code which implement binary tree. I want to apply a fold function on the tree. Here is the code-

```
data Btree a = Tip a | Bin (Btree a) (Btree a) deriving Show

foldbtree :: (a->a->a) -> Btree a-> a
foldbtree f (Tip x) = x
foldbtree f (Bin t1 t2) = (foldbtree f t1) f (foldbtree f t2)
```

But I am getting compilation error -

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t2 = t0 -> t1 -> t2
    In the return type of a call of `foldbtree'
    Probable cause: `foldbtree' is applied to too many arguments
    In the expression: (foldbtree f t1) f (foldbtree f t2)
    In an equation for `foldbtree':
        foldbtree f (Bin t1 t2) = (foldbtree f t1) f (foldbtree f t2)

bird_exercise.hs:206:47:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t1 = t0 -> t1 -> t2
    In the return type of a call of `foldbtree'
    Probable cause: `foldbtree' is applied to too few arguments
    In the fourth argument of `foldbtree', namely `(foldbtree f t2)'
    In the expression: (foldbtree f t1) f (foldbtree f t2)
```

Please help me regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is this in the last case:

```
foldbtree f (Bin t1 t2) = f (foldbtree f t1) (foldbtree f t2)
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `(foldbtree f t1) \`f\` (foldbtree f t2)`

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you should probably "cheat" and let GHC derive the `Foldable` instance of your datatype for you automatically, using the `DeriveFoldable` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

module XXX where

import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (Sum(..))

data Btree a = Tip a | Bin (Btree a) (Btree a) deriving (Show, Foldable)

sumTips :: Btree Int -> Int
sumTips = getSum . foldMap Sum
```

(The relevant bits are the `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}` pragma at the top of your .hs file and the `deriving (..., Foldable, ...)` clause in your datatype definition.) The `fold`, `foldMap`, etc. that come from the compiler-derived `Btree` instance of `Foldable` are almost certainly the ones you want anyway. While you're at it, you might also want to derive `Functor` and `Traversable` instances, which is done exactly as for `Foldable`. If you prefer, you can pass the `DeriveXXX` pragmas via cabal or the command line, although I like the specificity of per-file pragmas.